# heap space on a java host

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, heap-memory

I'm about to register in a java hosting plan on some website with unlimited disk space and traffic with **tomcat 7.0.2** as my server.

I'm planning to publish all the websites i develop with **JSF2** and some other technologies on this hosting, but i found out that i only have *64mb* heap space,  and I'm worried that this might be a problem if i have many apps running at the same time.

Any one has an opinion on how might this affect the server, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It most certainly won't be enough, even for one application. You can try it locally - run a tomcat and pass `-Xmx64m` as a JVM option, then see whether your applications run properly, or they throw Java Heap Space errors.

If you can't increase it, I'd suggest Amazon EC2. You can use a newer version of tomcat there as well.

Comment: @Bohzo : Is there any 'maximum' java heap for EC 2 ?

Comment: yes, it depends on the instance you are running. The smallest instance has around 700 MB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Before using your application in production, I recommend you:
- test your application with a testing tool such as JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- monitor the jvm of tomcat during your test with a tool such as jconsole. Analyse the needed memory for each use case.

You'll surely need to tune your memory to more than 64mb. 
It's difficult/impossible to give you the necessary amount of memory without knowing your web application.

Beware as well, if you use 64 bits JVM, the consumption could be twice for your objects (except if you use -XX:+UseCompressedOops)